# Shade for plants during wet season necessary or not

Tags: plant-health, plant-care

I have tomatos, beans, chilis, onions, and garlic plants, and also juvenile fruit tree (30cm) avocado, grapes, ficus carica, strawberry, papaya, and I think some outdoor flowers

I had oranges sprouts before but since oranges from seeds grows so so long though sprout fast and easily I ditched them.

I learned that all my plants and flowers thrive under “direct sun” but recently these months is wet season.
Im pretty sure my 25 liter of soil in polybag I grew them in will definitely get rained on often if I let all my plants outdoor, and I'm afraid of root rotting.

So I will be putting them near inside where there's roof top but they will get direct light if it’s sunny day during 7am until 10/11am while the rest is like just bright light without direct sun (you know what I mean).

My question is, do I have to put them (or some of them only) under shade mentioned above during wet season? And after wet season over maybe few months later idk, should I put them outside to get more light?

What exactly gardener usually will do during wet season do they put portable roof or something on tops their crops?

Comment: The shadest spot outdoors, protected from heavy rain, is sunnier than the sunniest spot indoors. Keep indoors as a last resort.

Comment: Ah.. okay. You make sense.